# Android How to Update column without the key in where clause

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-update

I have a table with an auto-increment key. But in my table the couple "UserID" , "CardID" is unique. 
I want to update a column using only UserID and CardID in the where clause. I don't want to use the key, is it possible?.

So my table have the following column : ID( the key) | UserID | cardID | isInMazzo| . 
I'm try to update the column isInMazzo in the following way:

```
String query = "UPDATE " +  MyCardsMetaData.TABLE_MYCARDS
            + " SET " + MyCardsMetaData.ISINMAZZO + " = ? "
            + " WHERE " + MyCardsMetaData.USERID + " = ? AND " + MyCardsMetaData.CARDID + " = ?";

mDb.rawQuery(query, new String[]{isInMazzo, String.valueOf(userID), String.valueOf(cardID)});
```

What happens when i execute this query? i'am having a lot of problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. Your query looks fine. It will only update column `MyCardsMetaData.ISINMAZZO` for a row where `MyCardsMetaData.USERID` equals `String.valueOf(userID)` and `MyCardsMetaData.CARDID` equals `String.valueOf(cardID)`. And if you're saying that these columns are unique - only one row will be updated.